# How to use redux with fela and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

fist thanks for your attention.
I am trying to use [fela](http://fela.js.org) for dynamically styling my component. Also for manage the states of app, we need to use [redux](http://redux.js.org/). In fela we need to use a `Provider` to wrap all component of app. also in redux we have the same thing. for example the root of the app we have :

```
import { createRenderer } from 'fela'
import { Provider } from 'react-fela'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import React from 'react'

const renderer = createRenderer()

render(
   <Provider renderer={renderer}>
     <App />
   </Provider>,
 document.getElementById('app')
)
```

and in root of redux app we have:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <App />
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```

And my problem is how to use this packages together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when use `as` syntax in import can solve this problem. for example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { Provider as FelaProvider } from 'react-fela'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
   <ReduxProvider store={store}>
       <FelaProvider>
           <App />
       </FelaProvider>
   </ReduxProvider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```